# Python 3 Project Euler Run Time

Tags: python

This is my solution to the [Project Euler Problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3):

```
def max_prime(x):
    for i in range(2,x+1):
            if x%i == 0:
                    a = i
                    x = x/i
    return a
max_prime(600851475143)
```

It takes too much time to run. What's the problem?

Comment: That's a mathematical problem. As every Euler problem, you have to find a mathematical solution to improve runtime.

Comment: Other than being slow, this algorithm doesn't give the right result. Consider your number is 8, you'll get 4 which isn't prime.

Comment: You can also cut the computations to half if you skip all the even number since they are not prime except 2. eg. range(2, x+1, 2)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- If you're using Python 3.x, use `//` for integer division instead of `/` (which will return a float).
- You solution doesn't account for the *multiplicity* of the prime factor. Take `24`, whose factorization is `2*2*2*3`. You need to divide `x` by `2` three times before trying the next number.
- You don't need to try all the values up to the initial value of `x`. You can stop once `x` has reached `1` (you know you have reached the highest divisor at this point).

Once you solve these three problems, your solution will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**==> projecteuler3.py**

```
import eulerlib

def compute():
    n = 600851475143
    while True:
        p = smallest_prime_factor(n)
        if p < n:
            n //= p
        else:
            return str(n)


# Returns the smallest factor of n, which is in the range [2, n]. The result is always prime.
def smallest_prime_factor(n):
    assert n >= 2
    for i in range(2, eulerlib.sqrt(n) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return i
    return n  # n itself is prime


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(compute())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is trying to iterate up to 600851475143, which isn't necessary.  You only need to iterate up to the square root of the largest prime factor.

```
from math import sqrt


def max_prime_factor(x):
    i = 2
    while i ** 2 <= x:
        while x % i == 0:  # factor out ALL multiples of i
            x //= i
        i += 1
    return x


print(max_prime_factor(600851475143))
```